# Reading and displaying multiple MRI images

Tags: image, matlab

I want to read 100 different MRI images in MATLAB using this code:

```
% Preallocate the 256-by-256-by-1-by-20 image array.
X = repmat(int16(0), [256 256 1 20]);
% Read the series of images.
 for p=1:20
   filename = sprintf('brain_%03d.dcm', p);
   X(:,:,1,p) = dicomread(filename);
end
% Display the image stack.
montage(X,[])
```

but this error is showing up:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

You have a subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. sprintf() is not of size (256x256), because `X(:,:,1,p)`is using the wrong dimensions.

Let's say that you wanted to store a 4 rows, 4 cols image. With intensity ranging from 0-255. Then you have a total of 16 elements, that each have a unique intensity value.

This
`(:,:,1)` implies N dimension, by N dimension by 1.

Given a 4x4 is `([1:4],[1:4],1)`.

`X(:,:,1,p)` is a **set of a set** of images.

Comment: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Error in Untitled19 (line 8)
   X(:,:,1,p) = dicomread(filename);

Answer (score 0):

The error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" occurs when the size of the array being assigned doesn't match the size of the array on the left side of the assignment.here, it seems the dimensions of the image you are trying to read are not consistent

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
X = repmat(int16(0), [256 256 1 20]);

for p = 1:20
    filename = sprintf('brain_%03d.dcm', p);
    img = dicomread(filename);

    if size(img, 1) == 256 && size(img, 2) == 256
        X(:,:,1,p) = int16(img);
    else
        fprintf('Error: Dimensions of %s do not match expected size.\n', filename);
    end
end

montage(X, [])
```

This modification includes a check to ensure that the dimensions of each image being read match the expected size of 256-by-256. If the dimensions do not match, it will print an error message.